# Visio 2010 - no rotate handles?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I'm using Visio 2010.  When I select a shape, I see the normal resize handles, but no rotation handles.  This seems to be the case for any shape I create.  This is not in a locked layer.

I have followed the directions here:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/select-move-resize-and-rotate-shapes-HP010357168.aspx#BM4

... but when I select the object, I see no rotate handle.  ONLY the resize ones.

How to I get my rotation handles back?

Comment: Can you provide the file? I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

**Shape Protection** can cause something like this behavior with Visio 2013, you should check to see if it is applied to your shape.

First enable the Developer tab on the Ribbon. Right-click anywhere on the Ribbon and click **Customize the Ribbon**.

[image]

The **Visio Options** dialog will launch and on the right side ensure that **Developer** is checked and then press **OK**.

[image]

Now **Select your shape**, go to the **Developer** tab in the Ribbon, and click **Protection**.

[image]

This will launch the **Protection** dialog. See if **Rotation** is checked. It is is uncheck it and press **OK**.

[image]

NOTE:

In my experience, when **Rotation** is protected:

- with Visio 2010 - the Rotation handle is visible, but grayed-out, and
  can't be used
- with Visio 2013 - the Rotation handle is invisible

Comment: For me rotation wasn't even checked. Rotation nib still missing. Hold alt then click a portion of the shape to rotate.

Comment: I unchecked Rotation for all the objects in my diagram but the thing will still not rotate.  ```Shape protection, container, and/or layer properties prevent complete execution of this command.```  And then nothing happens.  Why is this so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

Like Kevin said, "For me rotation wasn't even checked. (..) Hold alt then click a portion of the shape to rotate". Using alt seems to have turned on rotation by dragging. Nb. Visio 2016